# Warning: Cannot update a component while rendering a different component. ReactRedux.Consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am getting a warning in my web app and have read a lot of posts about the issue. Unfortunately I have not managed to resolve my problem and hope someone might have some advice. From what I can tell I need to find a  way of dispatching to the store in a useEffect. But my efforts so far have been unsuccessful.

The warning says:

> index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update a component (`Connect(TabMenuComponent)`) while rendering a different component (`ReactRedux.Consumer`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `ReactRedux.Consumer`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render

The stack trace further points me to this file. It points to line 30 which is the store.dispatch line:

```
export const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, roles, computedMatch, ignoreRedirection, ...rest }) => (
  <Route exact {...rest} render={props => {
    return <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
      {({ store }) => {
        const user = store.getState().appData.user;

        if (!user) {
          auth.setRedirectUrl(window.location.pathname);
          return <Redirect to={auth.loginUrl} />;
        }

        const redirectUrl = auth.getRedirectUrl();

        if (redirectUrl && !ignoreRedirection) {
          auth.removeRedirectUrl();
          return <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />;
        }

        if (roles && roles.length && !roles.some(neededRole => user.roles.some(userRole => userRole === neededRole))) {
          return <BaseLayout authError={stringKeys.error.unauthorized}></BaseLayout>;
        }

        store.dispatch({ type: "ROUTE_CHANGED", url: computedMatch.url, path: computedMatch.path, params: computedMatch.params })
        return <Component {...props} />;

      }}
    </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>;
  }
  } />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dispatching an action in the middle of a render which is not correct. What you should instead do is to create an HOC or a wrapper component to your input Component and dispatch the action once thee component is mounted

**With class component wrapper:**

```
class CompWithDispatch extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount()  {
    const { store, type, url, path, params } = this.props;
    store.dispatch({ type, url, path, params })
   }

   render() {
      const { store, type, url, path, params , component: Component,  ...rest} = this.props;
      return <Component {...rest} />
   }
}
```

**With function component wrapper**

```
const CompWithDispatch = (props) => {
    const { store, type, url, path, params, component:Component, ...rest } = props;
    useEffect(() => {
       store.dispatch({ type, url, path, params })
    }, []);
    return <Component {...rest} />

}
```

and use it like

```
export const AuthRoute = ({ component, roles, computedMatch, ignoreRedirection, ...rest }) => (
  <Route exact {...rest} render={props => {
    return <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
      {({ store }) => {
        const user = store.getState().appData.user;

        if (!user) {
          auth.setRedirectUrl(window.location.pathname);
          return <Redirect to={auth.loginUrl} />;
        }

        const redirectUrl = auth.getRedirectUrl();

        if (redirectUrl && !ignoreRedirection) {
          auth.removeRedirectUrl();
          return <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />;
        }

        if (roles && roles.length && !roles.some(neededRole => user.roles.some(userRole => userRole === neededRole))) {
          return <BaseLayout authError={stringKeys.error.unauthorized}></BaseLayout>;
        }

        const additionalProps = { type: "ROUTE_CHANGED", url: computedMatch.url, path: computedMatch.path, params: computedMatch.params })
        return <CompWithDispatch {...additionalProps} {...props} component={component}/>;

      }}
    </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>;
  }
  } />
);
```